# Define a custom git remote

Tags: git

I read this famous [article](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

[image]

I understand how **bob** and **clair** can sync with **origin**, but I don't understand the connection between **alice** and **bob** and **david** and **clair**.

The article says:

> [...]But besides the centralized push-pull relationships, each
>   developer may also pull changes from other peers to form sub teams.
>
> **Technically, this means nothing more than that Alice has defined a Git remote, named bob, pointing to Bob’s repository, and vice versa.**

Do I understand it correctly that two teams (**alice** and **david**) sync from origin but created their own git server endpoint to make it accessible to **bob** and **clair**?

Comment: How exactly they set this up is not defined. Maybe they have a team server where they can both push, or share a work directory, or maybe Alice has SSH login on Bob's workstation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Git, a *remote* is a short name—well, as long as you like—that stands in for a URL.  It does a little more than that, but that's its main initial job.

When you use `git clone` to *make* a Git repository, the `git clone` command adds one remote for you.  The standard name for this one remote is `origin`.  So most Git repositories have exactly one remote, named `origin`.

To add another remote, use:

```
git remote add
```

which takes two required parameters:

- the name of the remote to add, and
- the URL.

To see the URL attached to some repository, use `git remote -v` or `git config --get remote.name.url`:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@github.com/path/to/repo.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@github.com/path/to/repo.git (push)
$ git config --get remote.origin.url
ssh://git@github.com/path/to/repo.git
```

The `git remote` command reveals that each remote can in fact store *two* URLs.  The primary one, under `.url`, is used for both `git fetch` *and* `git push` by default.  If you set a second one using `remote.name.pushurl`, that one is used for `git push`, while the main one is used for `git fetch`.

If Alice is frequently going to fetch from Bob, she might do:

```
git remote add bob <url>
```

The URL here can be an `ssh://` URL, a `git://` URL, an `https://` URL, or a `file://` URL, or it can just be a local path (some folks use this sort of thing with network-shared drives or VMs).  Be aware that when using local paths, Git makes file system specific assumptions, if it can, that can result in weirdness when using network-shared drives and the like.  When using `file://` URLs, Git makes copies, so that if the network goes down you can still work locally.

Once you have a remote, `git fetch` to that remote will obtain their branch names, and copy their commits into your repository accordingly.  So Alice would typically end up with `bob/master`, and maybe `bob/feature` if Bob has a branch named `feature`.  But you can set additional settings under these various remote names.  Alice could configure her `bob` remote to pick up only some selected set of Bob's branch names, for instance.

Once you have *more than one* remote, `git fetch` with no arguments becomes interesting.  If you have only one remote, named `origin`, `git fetch` always fetches from the URL under your short name `origin`.  If you have two or more, which remote does `git fetch` use?  The answer is in [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch.html); see the **DESCRIPTION** section.

Note that the `--all` option to `git fetch` means *fetch from all remotes*.  Unless you have more than one remote defined, there is never any reason to use `git fetch --all`.

Answer (score 2):

First off let me say the diagram you're showing doesn't seem like a great example. It may be to understand git deeply but isn't necessarily common usage. That said there's a number of different ways that the pairs (alice, bob), (alice, david), and (david, clair) can sync without going through origin.

1. one pair could have set up a secondary origin that the push/fetch from. I sometimes have multiple origins (e.g. GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket)
2. one pair could sync to a network filesystem location. You can perform a git fetch from a filesystem location (e.g. `.../.git` or bare `.../reponame.git` directory). I sometimes do this for a fast local copy rather than recloning the second directory from origin.
3. maybe from time to time, one person just takes an actual copy of the other's `.git` directory as a restart point.

To expand on (2), let's say I already have a git versioned directory `advent-o-code-2019`

```
cd advent-o-code-2019
cd ..
mkdir temp-dir
cd temp-dir
git init
git fetch ../advent-o-code-2019/.git master
```

At this point the git state in `temp-dir` has created a new reference named `FETCH_HEAD` as well as all the ancestor objects to what was at master in the original repo. I would usually follow this with:

```
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!